# Setup for MacOS applications

Tags: java, macos, installation

I developed app (for mac) for which I would like to create a user-friendly instalation package. The file structure of the application is as follows:

```
───myApp.app
    └───Contents
        │   Info.plist
        │   PkgInfo
        │
        ├───Java
        │       myApp.jar
        │
        ├───MacOS
        │       JavaAppLauncher
        │
        ├───PlugIns
        └───Resources
            │   GenericApp.icns
            │
            └───en.lproj
                    Localizable.strings
```

Currently users have to install myApp by executing terminal command (If I just copy the application in Applications folder , it does not work):

```
sudo mv myApp.app /Applications/myApp.app
```

Is there any program (not necessary free) that creates installation process package (next, next, ... finish). On one of the steps process should check the version of Java on the user computer.
  Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

I [packages](http://s.sudre.free.fr/Software/Packages/about.html) app is what I was lookin for.